# Firebase not defined - Cloud Function

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-functions

I am making a call to a firebase function each 24 hour to delete some data. I have something like this

```
var firebase = require("firebase");
exports.deletedata = functions.https.onRequest((req, res) => {

     firebase.database().ref ....
     ...
     return firebase.database().ref().update(result);
  }
```

When I read the log it is saying Firebase not defined. Can I do something like this ?

Comment: Don't you need `firebase-functions` and `firebase-admin`, as are [shown here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started#import_the_required_modules_and_initialize)?

Comment: oh yes I got it working Thanks